# Output update of robot position coordiantes

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, husky, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I did a mapping of my static area with hector_slam using RP-Lidar 2D scanner and then i finished path planning using husky_slam, now i'm about to make my robot navigate through the map.

The issue is, i need to find a way that makes an output **that gives me updates of my rebot positon in relation of the goal point** each time it moves throught the path it planned already.
I searched the net for days without any luck.

What are your suggestions to fulfill my lack of need?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377814/output-update-of-robot-position-coordiantes/) by [anonymous72456](https://answers.ros.org/users/72456/anonymous72456/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [actionlib](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib).

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2021-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1